# Adobe pattern searching algorithm

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures

Which sorting algorithm does adobe reader use in its find function such that it is able to search any pattern out of a very large document within seconds?

Comment: You'd need to find someone with access to the codebase to give you an informative answer.

Comment: Based on observed speed, and comparing to things like grep searching a similar amount of text, my guess would be "none" -- it seems to just use a fairly normal substring search. Many of the others run, if anything, a bit faster (though it's not an entirely fair comparison since most PDFs will also require decompression).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure precisely what Adobe is using, but I would guess that it was some known fast string matching algorithm (perhaps Rabin-Karp, Boyer-Moore, or KMP) probably run in parallel across all the document pages at once.  For short text strings, this should be very, very fast.

Hope this helps!